# dequeue is called two time for single training batch

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a convolutional network using Tensorflow.
Input to the convolutional layer are 3 Chaneel Color Images and the output (Label) are single channel Images.
I am using tfrecord and queues. The dequeue op is given below

```
image, labelImage = queue.dequeue_many(BATCH_SIZE)
```

image goes as input to first convolutional layer and the labelImage is used to calculate loss.

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=img,filters=8,kernel_size=5,padding='SAME',activation=tf.nn.relu)
.....
.....
finaldeconv = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs=deconv2,filters=1,kernel_size=5,strides=(2,2),padding='SAME',activation=tf.nn.relu)
loss = tf.divide(tf.square(tf.subtract(labelImage,finaldeconv )),2)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
train = optimiser.minimize(cost)
```

So, now when I train inside session

```
 sess.run(train)
```

The op calls should be as follows for the above code:-

train op calls loss op.
loss op calls labeImage and finaldeconv
finaldeconv calls conv1
conv1 calls image

image and labelImage both call dequeop

I dont get image for conv layer and corresponding labelImage for calculating loss. image and LabelImage makes separate calls to deque. How can I fix this?

One way is to use placeholders and place image and labelImage to the placeholders, but I dont want to waist time in copying in gpu. I already have the queue on gpu.

Answer (score 0):

> image and labelImage both call dequeop

Yes, the **same** `dequeop`, in parallel.

Since you're not explicitly calling (using different `sess.run` calls) `image` or `labelImage`, you can be sure that `image` & `labelImage` go in pair.

If you're using a single `sess.run` call of the `train` operation **but** you're getting label values that are not correct for the input image, the problem is somewhere else: maybe your association image-label is wrong or you're calling `sess.run(op1)` and `sess.run(op2)` where `op1` uses `image` and `op2` uses `labelImage`.

In this context, `image` is the "previous" value of images and `imageLabels` are the labels associated with the actual (and not already fetched) images.

Comment: First of all thank you for replying.I want to confirm that I understood your answer correctly.
One training example, which is inserted in the queue is in list format ex-[image, labelImage].I have create queue as below:-

    queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=100,min_after_dequeue=2,dtypes=[tf.float32,tf.float32],shapes=[(IMAGE_ROWS,IMAGE_COLS,3),(IMAGE_ROWS,IMAGE_COLS)])

Now if I just call sess.run(train), Will it call the the dequeue op only once per itteration?
If so, image and labelImage are in pair and my problem will be solved.